# Solve differentiated equation at value in Matlab

Tags: matlab, math, calculus, differentiation

As a programming exercise I have written a Matlab function which finds the derivative of a function using the finite difference method. In a script I have called the function and wish to check it using the built-in functions, except I am having trouble implementing this.

In order to get a check I use diff(eqn) to get the differentiated equation, however I am not sure how to use this equation to then solve for a particular value, eg. x = 2.

Here is my code:

```
syms x

eqn= cos(x);

%set value for the derivative to be evaluated at
x2 = 2; 

%create function handle
f = @(x) cos(x); 

%call finite difference function
yderiv = derivative(f,x2) 

%use built-in to get differentiated function
ycheck = diff(eqn)
```

With the output:

> yderiv =
>      -0.9093
>
> ycheck =
>   -sin(x)

Any help on how to solve ycheck at x2, or a different approach to use would be most appreciated.

Cheers :)

Comment: `subs(ycheck, x2)` ? This substitutes the free symbolic variable (`x)` in `ycheck` by the value `x2`

Comment: Hey, if I edit the last part of my code to this: 
%use built-in to get differentiated function
ycheck = diff(eqn);
subs(ycheck, x, x2)

Then I get an output of:
yderiv = -0.9093
ans =-sin(2)

Comment: Nevermind! If I put eval(subs(ycheck, x, x2)) in I get a numerical answer! Thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score -2):

To calculate a derivative with finite differences you do not need the symbolic expressions you are using.

You need to:

1. Select your delta, for example `dx = 0.01`
2. Choose your range, let's say x = [0, 2*pi]. Create a variable for that range `x = 0:dx:2*pi`
3. Evaluate the function, something like `y = cos(x)`
4. Use the `diff` function
5. Divide by your `dx`.
6. Plot

The rest (getting the value of the derivative of y at x = 2) should be clear once you go through those steps.

Comment: This does not solve his problem how to evaluate `ycheck` at `x2`.